# Hosts file on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, hosts, savon

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP API that sits in a DMZ behind a firewall using a Ruby/Rack app and the Savon gem for SOAP, and HTTPI gem for requests/responses.

The SOAP API defines a wsdl file that points to an internal domain name behind the firewall (eg. "http://randomhostname/path/to/wsdl"), and that works fine when I define the ip to hostname in my /etc/hosts file locally on my machine (1.1.1.1 randomhostname).

The problem I run into, is that the production environment for my app runs on Heroku.
How can I map the external ip of the server I'm trying to connect to with the hostname defined in the wsdl on Heroku or in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the WSDL. Call the functions directly. Like this:

```
#!ruby

require 'savon'

stock_handle = ARGV[0] || 'OTEX'

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx'
  wsdl.namespace = 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/'
end

response = client.request :wsdl, 'GetQuote' do
  http.headers["SOAPAction"] = '"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote"'
  soap.body = { "symbol" => stock_handle }
end

print response
```

Comment: This worked, I actually was also able to connect by specifying the IP of the server as http.proxy within the Savon configuration settings, but I don't think that's as ideal.

Comment: I don't use the WDSL version for production code because every time you create a Savon::Client it parses the WSDL. I think that's a performance disadvantage but I haven't really measured it.